# Алгоритм для копирования, пока исходящая последовательность не закончится

Tags: c++, итераторы, copy

Есть алгоритм std::copy, который принимает 2 итератора на входящую и 1 на исходящую последовательность. Если ли подобный алгоритм, который принимает 2 итератора на исходящую последовательность и 1 на входящую? Если нет, то почему?

Comment: А где гарантия, что входящей хватит на всю выходящую? :)

Comment: @Harry нет гарантии, но это не повод не делать такую версию, ведь в текущей версии тоже нет гарантии, что исходящей хватит

Comment: это получается `std::generate`